# exception in list view in android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, adapter, android-6.0-marshmallow

I added a header to a list view
in the past When scrolling up or down throw exception
That was solved with a custom view list:

```
    public MyFixedListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyFixedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyFixedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public MyFixedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}


@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    try {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But now the Android 6.0.1 (marshmallow) , once again, the show was former error:
in my stack trase :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 : at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
```

add header :

```
private void Create_Header_Sjd_init() {

    LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertViewHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_idea_list , null);
    convertViewHeader.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_light_light));

    listView.addHeaderView(convertViewHeader, null, false);
}
```

Comment: is the header/footer static or do they scroll?

Comment: They are also scrollable @Tasos

Comment: check this tutorial if you spot anything that may help -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wOO91oLo2s

Comment: Pls show your custom adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resovle this error by sub code :

```
        listView.setFooterDividersEnabled(false);
    listView.addFooterView(new View(this), null, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

IndexOutOfBoundsException,maybe you can check you code about list of data or item view

Comment: I,m used endless list that is difficult

Answer (score 0):

If your list size id Zero then for adding header to list view you have set this..

```
listView.setAdapter(null);
```

Comment: with comment this line of code : addHeaderView() never throw exception

Comment: Please tell me when you are calling addHeaderView().Are you calling it in onScroll()

Comment: I call addheader() only one time and first loading